# Race conditions in Google Maps loading

Tags: html, google-maps, angularjs

I've been having a problem and no amount of googling has led to an answer. I'm building a web application that uses google maps and I keep getting race condition errors after initializing the map. I'm trying to just get the bounds of the map when the page loads, so I can use those boundaries to get data from my API. The problem is that I get incorrect bounds about 20% of the time.

The main things I'm trying to figure out is:

- When exactly is a map initialized so I can use it properly?
- Is having a fluid map container causing problems?
- Is angular.js causing problems for some reason.

The map is assigned to a div called `map-canvas` which is inside an absolutely positioned `map-container`

```
#map-container{
    position:absolute;  
    background-color:#DDD;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:450px;
    right:0px;
}

#map-canvas{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I'm using jQuery's `$(function(){})` method to be notified when the page is loaded. Then I call my initMap() function to initialize the map, where `myLatLng` is already defined. In order to detect when the map is initialized, I'm adding an 'idle' listener. The autopanning part is for detecting when a user is in the process of dragging the map.

```
$scope.initMap = function(){        
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatLng,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);            

    google.maps.event.addListener($scope.map, 'idle', function() {                      
        if($scope.autoPanning){
            $scope.autoPanning = false;
        }else{
            $scope.getStories();
        }
    });     
};
```

In my `getStories()` method, I get the bounds of the map so I can submit a query to my service. The problem is that latitude_1 will equal latitude_2, giving me essentially a line instead of a box as bounds. This is what I'm currently doing to catch and fix that error:

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();

    var bounds = {
        latitude_1 : ne.lat(),
        longitude_1 : ne.lng(),
        latitude_2 : sw.lat(),
        longitude_2 : sw.lng()
    };


if(bounds.latitude_1 == bounds.latitude_2){
    line("---caught invalid map event---------------------");

    google.maps.event.trigger($scope.map, 'resize');

    setTimeout(function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger($scope.map, "resize");            
        $scope.map.setCenter(myLatlng);  
    }, 1000);

    return;
}
```

I'm catching that invalid latitudes issue about 20% of the time, and it's really frustrating. Can anyone shine light on this issue?

Comment: Did you try with `bounds_changed` event? I had problem of undefined bounds when I tried to get bounds too early but not something like what you described.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what the problem was. It was based on a misunderstanding on my part about the `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`:

`$(document).ready` is fired when the DOM is ready for interaction.

`$(window).load` fires when all the page assets are loaded.

So window.load happens after document.ready. I was initializing my app on the document.ready event, when google maps assets weren't fully loaded. I switched my initialization code to happen on the window.load event and it works now.